# Best practice deploying kafka connector in a distributed mode on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kubernetes and trying to deploying kafka connector in a distributed mode on kubernetes. I am clear about the setting of the worker and connector properties, but what would the best practice for kubernetes deployment? Should I deploy two pods, each with one worker and the two workers from two pods sharing the same consumer/producer group-id? Or other configurations like two workers as two containers inside one pod? I hope my question is clear, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

You should deploy two or more pods with a consumer container per pod.

**Longer version:**

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. A pod is the smallest deployable units of computing in the kubernetes world. Two or more containers should sit alongside each other in a single pod if they are tightly coupled.

For your current use case, the benefit of using kubernetes (outside of many others) would be that you could horizontally scale the number of consumers with ease by increasing replicas, thereby increasing the number of pods. These consumers need to share the same consumer group id. (The story for producers would be similar as well)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks! It is very helpful. I just have two follow-up questions: 1) when you see "tightly coupled", what would be a good use case for that? 2) For the kafka connector in a distributed mode, the workers will have different rest.port numbers but sharing group-id. So it cannot be horizontally scaled just by increasing the replicas. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 1) A tightly coupled container is something that you may use for monitoring or log forwarding, which needs to sit close to the main container and access data that it pushes elsewhere. 2) I don't see why you need different port numbers for the consumers. As long as they sit inside their own pods, they are not going to have port conflicts with each other.

Comment: I mean to configure the different workers in a distributed mode, you need a different rest.port number for each worker. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html

Comment: Actually you don't if each worker sits in its own pod, as pods would have their own internal IPs. Can you try and see if that works?

Comment: So if we don't give the different rest.port number for different pod/worker, then it is just like the pod with replica size of 2. I don't think it would be the real distributed mode. Can you get the connectors re-balanced among the rest of the workers after one work is down? I don't think so.

Comment: Hey @Sophie what did you end up doing?